# React JS app project vs ASP.Net Core project with React JS pros and cons

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I’m new to React JS and would like to following on the selection of the presentation layer App project. I’m using ASP.Net core API survives for backend. I’ve found mainly 2 ways to create the frontend app project.

Option 1 - Create a react app using Node command “npx create-react-app” and working on the Visual Code without any C#.Net components and call the API services.

Option 2 - Create an ASP.Net Core MVC Project and add ReactJS.Net and continue working (https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html).

Following are the questions I’m having.

And If I follow the option 1 path, will it be difficult to manage the app security, routing, authentication and authorization etc.? Will there be any added support from ASP.Net Core in terms of handing security, routing, authentication and authorization?

What are the benefits of taking option 2 approach?

I would like to go for option 1 approach as setting up a pure JS app for frontend what are the challenges that I might face.

Thanks.